# MailKit MS Exchange. SMTP Authentification

Tags: authentication, smtp, mailkit

My application reads and sends mail through our MS Exchange mail server using Mailkit 2.15.0

Here is my code for reading

```cs
private static void ReadEmails()
{
    var client = new ImapClient(new ProtocolLogger("logs/imap.log", false));

    client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;

    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

    client.SslProtocols |= SslProtocols.Tls;

    client.Connect("our.ms.exchange.server.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);

    #region Auth Section

    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Clear();
    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Add("PLAIN");

    var saslMechanism = new SaslMechanismPlain("domain\\username", "password");

    client.Authenticate(saslMechanism);

    #endregion

    // reading

    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

Here is my code for sending

```cs
private static void SendEmail()
{
    using var client = new SmtpClient(new ProtocolLogger("logs/smtp.log", false));

    client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;

    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

    client.SslProtocols |= SslProtocols.Tls;

    client.Connect("our.ms.exchange.server.com", 25, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);

    #region Auth Section

    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Clear();
    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Add("PLAIN");

    var saslMechanism = new SaslMechanismPlain("domain\\usernaame", "password");

    client.Authenticate(saslMechanism);

    #endregion
    
    // sending

    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

The problem is that read authentication works fine, but an exception raised for sending

```
SmtpCommandException: 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type
```

I tried to put NTLM authentification to auth section

```cs
client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Clear();
client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Add("NTLM");

var saslMechanism = new SaslMechanismNtlm(new NetworkCredential("username", 
    "password", "domain"));

client.Authenticate(saslMechanism);
```

Exception again

```
MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: '535: 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful'
```

I'm sure the credentials are correct because mail reading works fine.
What can be send authentication?

Here is failed smtp.log

```
Connected to smtp://mail.SERVER.com:25/?starttls=when-available
S: 220 s-mail3.SERVER.local Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 10 Apr 2023 22:52:04 +0300
C: EHLO DEV-25
S: 250-s-mail3.SERVER.local Hello [192.168.243.26]
S: 250-SIZE 36700160
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-DSN
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-STARTTLS
S: 250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS
S: 250-AUTH NTLM
S: 250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-BINARYMIME
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250 XRDST
C: STARTTLS
S: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
C: EHLO DEV-25
S: 250-s-mail3.SERVER.local Hello [192.168.243.26]
S: 250-SIZE 36700160
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-DSN
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-AUTH NTLM LOGIN
S: 250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-BINARYMIME
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250 XRDST
C: AUTH NTLM ********
S: 334 TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAGAAYADgAAAAFgomiVL4Edxo2a2MAAAAAAAAAAMYAxgBQAAAABgOAJQAAAA9JAE4AVABFAEwATABFAEMAVABJAEsAQQACABgASQBOAFQARQBMAEwARQBDAFQASQBLAEEAAQAOAFMALQBNAEEASQBMADMABAAkAEkATgBUAEUATABMAEUAQwBUAEkASwBBAC4AbABvAGMAYQBsAAMANABzAC0AbQBhAGkAbAAzAC4ASQBOAFQARQBMAEwARQBDAFQASQBLAEEALgBsAG8AYwBhAGwABQAkAEkATgBUAEUATABMAEUAQwBUAEkASwBBAC4AbABvAGMAYQBsAAcACAD7Itjs5WvZAQAAAAA=
C: ********
S: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
```

Comment: You spelled NTLM wrong.

Comment: Excuse me. I made a typo when I made out the code for the question. Corrected, but it did not affect the result.

Comment: Add your failed smtp.log to the question so people can see what is going on. Otherwise all we can do is play guessing games.

Comment: Added my failed smtp.log

Comment: Ah, I just spotted that you are using MailKit 2.15.0 - NTLM was rewritten to be much better in 3.x, so try upgrading.

Comment: You can also get rid of the AuthemticationMechanisms.Clear() and Add("NTLM") calls - they are unnecessary, *especially* if you are explicitly specifying which SaslMechanism to use.

Comment: Prior to v3.x, MailKit was using Mono's NTLM implementation which did not properly handle a lot of the NTLM nuances and a lot of people had problems with it (which forced me to disable it by default for a while in 2.x). Rewrote it from scratch in 3.x and now it works much better and I don't think I've gotten any more bug reports about it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using an old (2.15.0) version of MailKit which had a buggy implementation of the NTLM authentication. Upgrade to 3.x or 4.x and it will (probably) work.